# defaultProps with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, functional-programming, styled-components

Hello guys I been looking in the internet trying to apply defaultProps to my components but nothing is working atm.

I will show you my code:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: none;
  :focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  ${props =>
    props.primary &&
    `
    background-color: ${props.theme.colors.primary};
    color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
    :hover {
        background-color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
        color: ${props.theme.colors.primary};
        border-style: solid;  
        border-color: ${props.theme.colors.primary}
    }
  `}
  ${props =>
    props.secondary &&
    `
    background-color: ${props.theme.colors.secondary};
    color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
    :hover {
        background-color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
        color: ${props.theme.colors.secondary};
        border-style: solid;  
        border-color: ${props.theme.colors.secondary}
    }
  `}
  ${props =>
    props.success &&
    `
    background-color: ${props.theme.colors.success};
    color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
    :hover {
        background-color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
        color: ${props.theme.colors.success};
        border-style: solid;  
        border-color: ${props.theme.colors.success}
    }
  `}
   ${props =>
     props.warning &&
     `
    background-color: ${props.theme.colors.warning};
    color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
    :hover {
        background-color: ${props.theme.colors.blank};
        color: ${props.theme.colors.warning};
        border-style: solid;  
        border-color: ${props.theme.colors.warning}
    }
  `}
`;

export default Button;
```

I just want to setup defaultProps to give some styled by default if I dont do for example:

```
<Button primary>Text</>
```

Here is another example, this is a bit different:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrap = styled.input`
  ${props =>
    props.primary &&
    `
    border: 2px ${props.theme.colors.primary} solid;
  `}
  ${props =>
    props.secondary &&
    `
    border: 2px ${props.theme.colors.secondary} solid;
  `}
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  :focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

const Input = ({
  type,
  onChange,
  placeholder,
  primary,
  secondary,
  className,
  value,
  name,
  ref,
  children
}) => {
  return (
    <Wrap
      type={type}
      onChange={onChange}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      primary={primary}
      secondary={secondary}
      value={value}
      name={name}
      ref={ref}
      className={className}
    >
      {children}
    </Wrap>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Any help will be useful, Im trying to make a Theme for myself as clean as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Is there wrong with the way you pass props to styled-component <Button primary>Text</>? I think it should be: <Button primary={primary}>Text<Button/>

Comment: No, right now passing <Button primary>Whatever</Button> is working fine. I just want to add a defaultProps in case I dont add the “primary” or any other one. For example props.primary be my default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) to components works out of the box, even with components created from Styled Components. You need to define the defaultProps on the component. Here's a complete example from a fresh `create-react-app` application:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const ButtonBlue = styled.button`
  background-color: ${props => props.actuallyMakeItGreen ? 'green' : 'blue'};
`;

ButtonBlue.defaultProps = {
  actuallyMakeItGreen : true
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <ButtonBlue>Cool</ButtonBlue>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Creates a button that looks like this:

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const ButtonBlue = styled.button`
  background-color: ${props => props.actuallyMakeItGreen ? 'green' : 'blue'};
`;

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ButtonBlue>Cool</ButtonBlue>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

The only thing changing here is inside the `defaultProps` property, where we default `actuallyMakeItGreen` to true rather than false.

Answer (score -2):

First ensure you've passed your props into the styled component

```
<Button props={this.props} />
```

Then in your styled component you should be to format like so

```
const Button = styled.button`
  ${({ props }) => `
    color: ${props.color};
  `}
`
```

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand your recommendation of forwarding props of the parent component into the button (which is what `props={this.props}` is going to do). I'm not sure I understand what this is supposed to achieve or how it relates to defaulting props. Could you expand on this?